# Configure GCS bucket to allow public write but not overwrite

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

On Google Cloud Storage, I want PUBLIC (allUsers) to be able to upload new files and to download existing files, but I don't want PUBLIC to be able to overwrite an existing file.

Background: Upload and download URLs are typically determined by my own app. So under normal conditions there is no problem because the app guarantees that URLs are always unique when writing. But a malicious user could hack my app and would then potentially be able to upload files (bad) to my cloud storage and overwrite existing files (very bad).

I know I could solve this problem by proxying through App Engine or by using signed URLs, which I am trying to avoid due to timing constraints. Timely processing is essential as my app processes files (almost) in realtime and an extra delay of just 1,000 msec for processing two consecutive requests would be too long.

Would it be possible to configure cloud storage in a way that an error is returned in case an already existing file is hit during an upload, such as for example:

Bucket: PUBLIC has WRITE access
Individual file: PUBLIC has READ access

Would that work? What happens in GCS if bucket and file ACLs are contradictory? In above example the bucket would allow write access, but if the upload hits an already existing file with readonly access, would such request be honored by GCS, or would GCS consider the file as already inexistent at that point and replace it with the new content?

Any other approach that might work would be very appreciated.

Comment: The timing issue is interesting. Would it be possible for your server to hand out several signed URLs in advance of their being needed?

Comment: Yes @Brandon, thank you for the idea. I have been thinking about this as well, and if nothing else comes up, then I will probably use this route.

Comment: I finally went with your suggestion of keeping multiple signed URLs in advance. Works well despite of quite some CPU load for signing, but until now this really seems to be the only viable solution. [To collect your credits @BrandonYarbrough, post an answer so I can confirm it as correct.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to set these IAM roles on the bucket:

- roles/storage.objectCreator
- roles/storage.objectViewer

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles states:

"objectCreator allows users to create objects. Does not give permission to view, delete, or overwrite objects."